# Building libcap2 2.32 from source to deb pacakges fails

Tags: 20.04, dpkg, compiling

I am trying to build libcap2 2.32 from source to DEB packages on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS using the standard Ubuntu repository and am encountering following problem:

```
make[3]: *** Keine Regel vorhanden, um das Ziel „src/libcap/psx/psx.go“,
 benötigt von „pkg/linux_amd64/libcap/psx.a“, zu erstellen. Schluss.

ln -s /home/administrator/downloads/libcap2/libcap2-2.32/psx src/libcap/
make[3]: Verzeichnis „/home/administrator/downloads/libcap2/libcap2-2.32/go“ wird verlassen
make[2]: *** [Makefile:14: all] Fehler 2
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/home/administrator/downloads/libcap2/libcap2-2.32“
dh_auto_build: error: make -j2 "INSTALL=install --strip-program=true" CC=cc BUILD_CC=cc returned exit code 2
make[1]: *** [debian/rules:29: override_dh_auto_build] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/administrator/downloads/libcap2/libcap2-2.32“ wird verlassen
make: *** [debian/rules:25: binary] Fehler 2
dpkg-buildpackage: Fehler: Unterprozess debian/rules binary lieferte Exitstatus 2
```

> *** No rule available to build target „src/libcap/psx/psx.go“ required by „pkg/linux_amd64/libcap/psx.a“. End.

This outcome appears when I tried to build the package with `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot --no-sign`. I have tried to build this using `make` and then `sudo make install` and had no issues with this. The package has not been modified since downloading it using `apt-get source libcap2` from official Ubuntu repositories. I already have installed the build dependencies for this package and had a look at the package documentation but it only mentions the local build using make.

UPDATE:
I have succeeded building the 2.25 version from Ubuntu Bionic repository. When the same is tried using the newer version 2.43 from the groovy repository or 2.44 from the hirsute repo, then the build fails due to the some files missing:

```
dh_missing: error: missing files, aborting
make[1]: *** [debian/rules:78: override_dh_missing] Fehler 255
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/administrator/downloads/libcap2/test/libcap2-2.44“ wird verlassen
make: *** [debian/rules:28: binary] Fehler 2
dpkg-buildpackage: Fehler: Unterprozess debian/rules binary lieferte Exitstatus 2
```

Comment: What was wrong with installing it from [the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/libcap2)? What is your final idea on the compilation?

Comment: @N0rbert The files do come from that repository. I have downloaded them again and tried to build them using the `apt-get source --compile libcap2` command but I'm still getting the same error. I need to build the package from source because I have to get rid of Ubuntu branding for [this](https://ubuntu.com/legal/intellectual-property-policy) reason (see Point 3, 7th bullet point). The compilation fails with unmodified source code though.

Comment: Can't reproduce error. I'm using fresh 20.04 LTS inside docker container.

Comment: Interesting. In my case it's Ubuntu 20.04.1, dpkg 1.19.7, make 4.2.1, gcc 9.3.0 and glibc 2.31-0ubuntu9.1.